Image of submodule to a quotient
Let $M,M'$ be $A$ modules. Let $N\le M$ be a submodule also $M' \le M$ is a submodule. Let $f:M\to \frac{M}{M'}$ be the natural $A$ module homomorphism. Claim, $f(N)= {(N+M')}/{M'}$
I wish to know if my argument is correct.
Let $f(N)=\left\{\bar{n} \in \frac{M}{M'}: n \in N\right\}$. Let $\bar{n} \in f(N).$ Then, $\bar{n}=\overline{n+0}$. Hence $f(N) \subseteq (N+M')/M'$. Conversely, suppose $\overline{n+m'} \in (N+M')/M'$. Then $\overline{n+m'}=\overline{n}+\overline{m'} = \overline{n}$ , and thus $(N+M')/M' \subseteq f(N)$. Hence the claim.

You mean that $M'$ is a submodule of $M$ right?

Yes, $M'$ is a submodule of $M$.

I would say this is right, but it's not clear that you understand the crux of what's happening here.
Say $N, M'$ are submodules of $M$ an $A$-module.
Say $\pi \colon M \to M/M'$ natural quotient.
What's not clear is how the quotient $N$ by $M'$ under $\pi$ works because, of course, it's possible neither $N$ nor $M'$ contains the other so $M'$ may not be a submodule of $N$. To make this well-defined, we $\textit{need}$ to say $N$ maps to $N + M'$ first. (Note $N+M'$ is the smallest submodule of $M$ containing $N$ and $M'$.) Therefore, what's really happening here is the following:
$0 \to N \hookrightarrow N + M' \overset{\pi|_{N+M'}}\to (N + M')/M' \to 0$
This map is surjective as a composite morphism with kernel $N \cap M$ so $(N + M')/M' \cong N/(N \cap M)$ by 1st isomorphism theorem.
Therefore, I'd say your proof is not 'wrong' but isn't getting at this core.
